# Expansion of $\log(x+\{x\})$ at $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analysis, taylor-expansion

Can we expand $\log(x+\{x\})$ in a series
\begin{equation}
\log(x+\{x\}) = \log(x) + \frac{\{x\}}{x} - \frac{\{x\}^2}{2x^2} + \ldots, x \to \infty
\end{equation}
in the same way as
\begin{equation}
\log(x+y) = \log(x) + \frac{y}{x} - \frac{y^2}{2x^2} + \ldots, x \to \infty
\end{equation}
where $\{x\}$ is a fractional part of number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x \to \infty$ you can suppose that $x>1$. Hence
$$\log(x + \{ x \}) - \log x = \log \left( 1+ \frac{\{ x \}}{x} \right)$$
Now $$0\le \frac{\{ x \}}{x} < 1$$
so you are allowed to expand the Taylor series $\log(1+y)$ (the radius of convergence is $1$), where $y=\frac{\{ x \}}{x}$.